# how to match two lines and subtract them

Tags: awk

I have one file with two column , I want to match column two with every value in column two if they are matched subtract column one from column one of the two matched value of column one

```
7.788244 0
7.800744 1
7.813244 2
7.825744 3
7.838244 4
7.850744 5
7.863244 6
7.875744 7
7.888244 8
7.900744 9
7.913244 10
7.925744 11
7.938244 12
7.950744 13
7.963244 14
7.975744 15
7.801751 0
7.814251 1
7.826751 2
7.839251 3
7.851751 4
7.864251 5
7.876751 6
7.889251 7
7.901751 8
7.914251 9
7.926751 10
7.939251 11
7.951751 12
7.964251 13
7.976751 14
7.989251 15
```

example

```
0.013507
0.013507
0.013507
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
awk '{a[$2]?b[++i]=$1-a[$2]:a[$2]=$1}END{for(;x<length(b);) print b[++x]}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'a[$2]?a[$2]-=$1:a[$2]+=$1 {next} END {for (i in a) print -a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{if(a[$2]){print $1-a[$2]}else{a[$2]=$1;}}' your_file
```